# Necesito ayuda con una query

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

Me gustaría saber si alguien sabe como hacer que se vayan sumando los valores de una columna ejemplo:

```
id | Fecha      | Efectivo | TC | TD | Otro | Total | Obtenido | Resta | Acomulado

1  | 18/07/2016 | 5861     | 0  | 0  | 0    | 5861  | 650      | 5211  | 5211

3  | 20/07/2016 | 521      | 0  |0   | 0    | 521   | 0        | 521   | RES = 5211 + 521 = 5732

4  | 20/07/2016 | 20       | 0  | 0  | 0    | 20    | 10       | 10    | RES = 5732 + 10 = 5742
```

No sé si se alcance a entender la tabla pero explicado con palabras, de mi query de SQL tengo esas cabeceras que se muestran arriba y lo que quiero hacer es que en acomulado se vaya sumando lo anterior a la fila siguiente, de la columna resta, seria algo como esto: `valor coluna anterior + valor columna actual = acomulado` y así sucecivamente.

No sé si les sirva de algo la query que utilizo pero igualmente la dejo:

```
SELECT C.iidCorte 'Folio de corte'
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), C.dfechaIn, 103) Fecha
    ,(
        SELECT ISNULL(SUM(fTotal), 0) efectivo
        FROM catVentas
        WHERE iidMetodopago = 1
            AND iidCorte = C.iidCorte
        ) Efectivo
    ,(
        SELECT ISNULL(SUM(fTotal), 0) 'Tarjeda de credito'
        FROM catVentas
        WHERE iidMetodopago = 2
            AND iidCorte = C.iidCorte
        ) 'Tarjeda de credito'
    ,(
        SELECT ISNULL(SUM(fTotal), 0) 'Tarjeda de debito'
        FROM catVentas
        WHERE iidMetodopago = 3
            AND iidCorte = C.iidCorte
        ) 'Tarjeda de debito'
    ,(
        SELECT ISNULL(SUM(fTotal), 0) 'Otro'
        FROM catVentas
        WHERE iidMetodopago = 8
            AND iidCorte = C.iidCorte
        ) 'Otro'
    ,SUM(V.fTotal) Total
    ,(SUM(V.fTotal) - SUM(V.fResta)) Obtenido
    ,SUM(V.fResta) Resta
FROM catCortes C(NOLOCK)
    ,catVentas V(NOLOCK)
    ,catMetodosPago M
WHERE C.iidCorte = V.iidCorte
    AND V.iidMetodoPago = M.iidMetodopago
    AND C.dfechaUp BETWEEN '2016-01-01T00:00:00'
        AND '2017-05-17T23:59:59'
GROUP BY C.iidCorte
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), C.dfechaIn, 103)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que yo conozca hay dos formas, te las muestro con un ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @Tabla TABLE(
    id      int,
    Monto   NUMERIC(15,2)
)

INSERT INTO @Tabla (id, Monto)
SELECT 1,310 UNION
SELECT 2,112 UNION
SELECT 3,24  UNION
SELECT 4,43  UNION
SELECT 5,55 


-- 1 por join
SELECT  t1.id, 
    t1.Monto, 
    SUM(t2.Monto) as Acumulado
    FROM @Tabla t1
    INNER JOIN @Tabla t2 ON t1.id >= t2.id
    GROUP BY t1.id, t1.Monto
    ORDER BY t1.id

-- 2 usando PARTITION a partir de SQL 2012
SELECT  t.id,
    t.Monto,
    SUM(t.Monto) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Acumulado
    FROM @Tabla t
    ORDER BY t.id
```

Espero te sirva